# Embedding a horizontal scrollview in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

how would I go to embed a horizontal scrollview as shown on the image below. I've put a collectionview as my buttons that should be marked when the user is on either "page" of the scrollview. What I'm stuck on is the scrollview part. I put the scrollview where it should be and then my plan is to put a new view on it thats width is scrollview.bounds.width * 2. Then I'd put whatever I need on each "page" of that view. Is there a way to do it from storyboard ? Thanks.
ps here is the imgur link if image isn't shown https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMU8V.jpg
[image: image of my horizontal scrollview]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. First add a UIView inside your UIScrollView and make sure it sticks to all sides using Auto Layout. Then explicitly set the width of the UIView (your 'content view') to any value you like. You can also keep a reference to this constraint so you can change it later in code. Then you can add your subviews to this 'content view' and you should be good to go.